# const object as a data member vs normal variable

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a `Container` class that will be using an object of a class `Comparator` which will be passed through the template.

So I am doing something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Container{
    const T c;
};


struct Comparator{
    public:
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b)const{
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main(){
    Container<Comparator> container;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to compile this code I am getting the following error:

```
e.cpp:28:27: error: uninitialized const member in 'class Container<Comparator>'
   28 |     Container<Comparator> container;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~
e.cpp:16:13: note: 'const Comparator Container<Comparator>::c' should be initialized
   16 |     const T c;
      |
```

To get rid of this error what I did is just added a default constructor in the `Comparator` class:

```
struct Comparator{
    public:
    Comparator(){
        
    }
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b)const{
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

But the weird thing I observed is that when I am making a const object of the class `Comparator` as a normal variable (not the data member of any class) I am not getting any kind of error.

```
struct Comparator{
    public:
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b)const{
        return a < b;
    }
};

int main(){
    const Comparator comp;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is why I am getting errors when making a const object of the `Comparator` type within a class and not when making a normal const object of the same type?

Comment: `Container() : c{} {}` in the `Container` class also solves the problem.

Comment: @mch yes, I have tried it too. But what I want to ask is why we do not need to do anything when making a normal variable while within the class we either need a constructor or do something like you mentioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no initializer is given for the `const Comparator` variable it must be *const-default-constructible*. But your class `Comparator` is const-default-constructible because it has no non-static data members. For actual rules determining that see [[dlc.init.general]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init#general-7.sentence-2).

This is not only the requirement for such a variable, but also the requirement to not cause the implicit default constructor to be deleted if a class has an analogues non-static member without initializer, see [[class.default.ctor]/2.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class#default.ctor-2.4).

So your original code should compile. MSVC does compile it, but GCC and Clang do not.

The relevant requirement for the class members was however changed to the referenced wording with a defect report: [CWG 2394](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2394). Before that it required the member to have a user-provided default constructor, which is a stronger requirement than being const-default-constructible and which is exactly what you did add to make it work.

According to both the [Clang implementation status page](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) and the [GCC implementation status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-dr-status.html) the status of their implementation of the DR is unknown.